# How does one create an arithmetic tree recursively with return of void in C given an array of characters?

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree

How do I create an arithmetic tree recursively? I am given an array of characters of char* prefix. if I create a recursive function of insert, I'm confused as to how I'm going to keep track of where I am in the array of characters while iterating through it.

```
BTNode* insert(BTNode* node, char* c)
{
  BTNode* newnode = (BTNode*)malloc(sizeof(BTNode));
  if (c >= "0" && c<= "9") // it is an operand
  {
    newnode->left = NULL;
    newnode->right = NULL;
    newnode->item = c;
    return NULL;
  }
  else //it is an operator 
  {
    newnode->item = *c;
    newnode->left = insert(node->left, *(c+1);
    newnode->right = insert(node->right, *(c+1));
  
    return newnode;
  }
}

void createExpTree(BTNode** root,char* prefix)
{
 //Write your code here
  int index = 0;
  while (prefix[index] != '\0')
  {
    insert(*root, prefix[index]);
    index++;
  }
  
  
}
```

Note the input is in prefix.

The function has to return void because it is given as void, as the main function cannot be changed, shown below.

```
int main()
{
    char prefix[SIZE];
    BTNode* root=NULL;

    //printf("Enter an prefix expression:\n");
    gets(prefix);

    createExpTree(&root, prefix); // this should create the whole tree

    // printf("The Infix Expression:\n");
    printTree(root);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I understand the notion of expression Tree and how to create one writing it out myself, breaking down the tree into smaller and simpler trees.

Sample input:  +  99  *  -  88  77  +  /  66  -  55  44  33

(the output is supposed to be traversal of the tree in inorder and postorder, but I'm having trouble just creating the tree)

Sample output:
99 + 88 - 77 * 66 / 55 - 44 + 33
99 88 77 - 66 55 44 - / 33 + * +
528.00

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive? Why does the function need to be returning nothing?

Comment: "Note the input is in prefix." Which input? I don't see any. Did you forget to show some sample input?

Comment: What is the purpose of the shown code? Showing your own code is generaly good, but I don't get what it is supposed to demonstrate. Apart from the fact that code for demonstrating something should be in the form of a [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry for the unclear question, I've added additional details and the main function.

Comment: That there `BTNode** root` argument is a pointer to a pointer — there’s where you put the tree you are building. You need to hit your course notes pretty hard if you are going to make it through this one. Building an expression tree is a non-trivial exercise.

Comment: You added a separate main function. But please provide a [mre],

Comment: @Dúthomhas I understand, my course instructor barely explains a thing or 2 ... I've been great so far but binary tree (recursions in general) has been a pain for me

Comment: @Yunnosch I hope I made it neater and a little clearer... Sorry I'm don't quite understand how people like the questions to be formatted in, previously it was too little details and flagged down, now its too messy and all over the place right..?

Comment: There is a detailed explanation of how to make a [mre] and how you can tell that your code is not one. Also why MREs are useful for you and for the people who try to help you. The code fragments you show even after the second attempt give me the impression that you did not really read the link I provided. Info on general tips for making a good question are here [ask]. And since you did not even bother to take the [tour] allow me to recommend that first introduction to the ideas of StackOverflow. These links should provide you some insight on "how people like the questions to be formatted".

Comment: There are two problems, or should I say groups of problems, in this code. One has to do with strings. You are not handling strings correctly. Your compiler should warn you about ` char` and `char *` not being compatible. Fix these errors. `c >= "0"` is wrong and belongs to the same group of errors.

Comment: The other error or group of errors is more difficult. Consider a simple expression, say `2 + 3`. Your tree root should be `+`, the number 2 should be the left child, and the number 3 should be the right child of the root. Now look t your code. How can it make anything that comes before the `+` the left child? It only looks at things that come after.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the input will always be prefix. so It should be + 2 3 . I understood ur earlier correction though, the one on char, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Sorry did not realise it is a prefix expression.

Comment: I want to give an answer, but the way the function is currently prototyped it cannot be written recursively. Are you sure the function itself is meant to be called recursively? Or was the word “recursion” used to describe the tree structure?